# problem with making package - file not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all

the command:

```
faps@UbuntuBioMech:~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials$ make
```

occurs following failures:

```
    faps@UbuntuBioMech:~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials$ make
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_lisp
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
[  0%] Built target rospack_gensrv
[ 12%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
[ 37%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
[ 50%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
[ 50%] Built target rospack_genmsg
[ 50%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:15:47: error: ‘beginner_tutorials’ was not declared in this scope
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:15:33: error: parse error in template argument list
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:15:93: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient(const char [13])’
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:15:93: note: candidates are:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1129:17: note: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient(const string&, bool, const M_string&)
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1149:17: note: template<class Service> ros::ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient(const string&, bool, const M_string&)
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:16:3: error: ‘beginner_tutorials’ is not a class or namespace
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:16:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘srv’
/home/faps/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:17:3: error: ‘srv’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
faps@UbuntuBioMech:~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials$
```

What should i do?

Many Thanks in advance
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42577/problem-with-making-package---file-not-found/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems that you are using a service (AddTwoInts).
Check that you have the correct service definition (under ./srv/AddTwoInt.srv usually) or include the correct package in your manifest file.

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0